# Can Ethereum's geth be used with other mainnets?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I would like to set up a series of nodes, on different mainnets, that I can then query directly.  Geth looks like it works for Ethereum, but would I be able to use the `--networkid` command to connect geth to other networks e.g. `--networkid 137` for Polygon?  From the docs it looks like it should work, but elsewhere heimdall and bor are mentioned. Does anyone know if Geth would work?